# Is there a CoreFoundation equivalent that generates the same string when calling [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

When i use NSBundle:

```
NSString *path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
```

path1 holds

```
@"/Users/username/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3-64/Applications/2EDB/appname.app"
```

When I use CFBundle:

```
    CFURLRef path2 =CFBundleCopyResourcesDirectoryURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle());
```

path2 holds

```
@"file:///Users/username/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.0.3-64/Applications/2EDB/appname.app/"
```

Is there a CoreFoundation equivalent I can use to generate the same string as path1? (Without the "file://" and "%20" as proper spaces.) Or would I need to do extra processing to remove those myself? I need to use it in a c++ only class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one gives you a string, the second gives you a URL. Use the `CFURLCopyFileSystemPath` function to get a proper file path from the file URL.

```
CFStringRef filepath = CFURLCopyFileSystemPath(path2, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle);
```

Comment: Yes, this is better than my answer.